# DDD element: Aggregates in c#

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregate

When analyzing life cycle of domain objects, aggregate is basic element for objects grouping.
I am having trouble implementing aggregetes in C#.

One short example, with couple of classes, would be very helpful.
Or any link on this theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Order {
    public int OrderNumber { get; private set; }
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; private set; }
    public Address BillingAddress { get; private set; }
    private readonly IList<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; private set; }
    public void AddItem(Item item, int quantity) {
        OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine(item, quantity);
        OrderLines.Add(orderLine);
    }
    // constructor etc.
}

class OrderLine {
    public Item Item { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }        
    public OrderLine(Item item, int quantity) {
        Item = item;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

At no point should logic involving `OrderLine`s be exposed outside of an instance of `Order`. That's the point of aggegrate roots.

For a .NET specific reference, see [Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202). Of course, the standard reference here is [Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) . There's a good article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419654.aspx) too.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Udi Dahans](http://www.udidahan.com/) blog and [Greg Youngs](http://codebetter.com/blogs/gregyoung/) blog. A lot of great stuff there concerning DDD and CQRS. A lot of good questions and answers can be found and the Yahoo Doman Driven Design group. I know I haven't linked to a specific example, but if you look in this links you will find a lot of material and examples.